# Different content type for different elements of form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, multipartform-data

I am unable to send `content-type application/json` with the first element of my form data.

My code:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('addBank', JSON.stringify(reqData.addBank[0]));
fd.append('bankProof', reqData.bankProof);
var promise  = $http.post(url, fd, { transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}});
```

When I try to set the `content-type` for first key value pair, it makes the data blank in the request.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Content-Type: application/json to be set for addBank

Answer (score 2):

You can set value appended to `FormData` object as a `Blob` with data set to `JSON` and `type` set to `"application/json"`

```
fd.append("addBank"
, new Blob([JSON.stringify(reqData.addBank[0])], {type:"application/json"}));
```

Comment: Not getting data for addBank------
WebKitFormBoundaryaRSVPSAq0VUhqJ8l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addBank"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json


------WebKitFormBoundaryaRSVPSAq0VUhqJ8l
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bankProof"; filename="kyc.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryaRSVPSAq0VUhqJ8l--

Comment: What do you mean by "Not getting data"?

Comment: It is not sending the json. The request is blank for that key

Comment: @PurvaArora _"It is not sending the json. The request is blank for that key"_ How do you determine that the `FormData` objected `POST`ed at request is "blank for that key"?

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundarylFvcylcNTGG07ARG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="addBank"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json


------WebKitFormBoundarylFvcylcNTGG07ARG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bankProof"; filename="kyc.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarylFvcylcNTGG07ARG--

Comment: @PurvaArora That is the `multipart/form-data` which includes the `"addBank"` key and property at `name="addBank"; filename="blob" Content-Type: application/json`. Are you expecting the `JSON` to be displayed in plain text at the screen that you are reviewing the `multipart/form-data`? How is the `multipart/form-data` processed at server?

Comment: How can I retrieve this json from blob file in my java code?

Comment: _"How can I retrieve this json from blob file in my java code?"_ How is Java related to original Question?

Comment: In my api, I am parsing the json based on their keys, That is why I wanted to send data in json format.

Comment: `FormData` converts `Blob` passed to a `File` object. You can retrieve the `JSON` at server by getting the contents of the `File` object at key `"addBank"` at server, in the same manner which a file uploaded at an `<input type="file">` element within a submitted `<form>` is processed at server.